# React onclick event not working with custom function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React onclick event doesn't work when click Customer function and doesn't show anything in the console:

```js
      const Theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
    
      let Customer = (item)=> { 
        console.log( 'item');
        Theme.setCustomer(item);
      }
```

When click event don't work

```html
          <tbody>
            {
              customers.map((card) => (
                <tr key={card._id} onClick={ () => { Customer(card); } }>
                  <td>{card.name}</td>
                  <td>{card.phone}</td>
                  <td>{card.email}</td>
                  <td>{card.address}</td>
                  <td>{card.notes}</td>
                </tr>
              ))
            }
          </tbody>
```

Comment: It would help us if you explained what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I want add card item to Customer the event work when build but don't work any event when dev how fix it